# Keep prettyfaces extensionless URLs as “to-view-Id” within faces-config.xml

Tags: prettyfaces

How do I keep Prettyfaces created extensionless URLs in the `to-view-id`(s) within `faces-config.xml` so that it doesn't append `.xhtml` to the end of it ?

For e.g. while defining a navigation case, I define a `to-view-id` as `/topics/54233` but faces-config redirects me to `/topics/54233.xhtml` which I surely want to prevent. How do I do it ?

I'm aware that there exists Prettyfaces navigation techniques but I can't work with Prettyfaces for navigation(as it doesn't allow creating different navigation cases for an outcome based on different from-view-id(s) which is offered by faces-config.xml) so I'm rather trying to keep that job with faces-config.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you cannot use "prettyfaces URLs" in `faces-config.xml` due to the architecture of the faces navigation system. (By the time faces-config.xml is processed for navigation, all other extensions have given up their chance to act.)

This means you need to use the original JSF view-id URL in the `to-view-id` of your navigation case, and you *must* use `<redirect/>` in order for PrettyFaces to modify the outbound URL and rewrite it to the pretty form.

Something like this

```
<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>from-outcome</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/topics/view.xhtml</to-view-id>
    <redirect>
        <view-param>
            <name>id</name>
            <value>54233</value>
        </view-param>
    </redirect>
</navigation-case>
```

If you have an appropriate mapping in your `pretty-config.xml`, PrettyFaces will issue a redirect to `/topics/54233`

```
<url-mapping>
    <pattern value="/topics/#{id}" />
    <view-id value="/topics/view.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>
```

All this put together will result in a successful redirect. In general, though, if you are going to do work in faces-config.xml, you just need to pretend that PrettyFaces doesn't exist, and remember to use `<redirect/>`.

Comment: Thanks Lincoln. Very helpful answer! What do you think rather than all this, would it be more nicer if I move the navigation to prettyfaces ? For that to work like faces-config navigation, should I be using different outcomes for different `from-view-id`s to create different nav cases in Prettyfaces ?

Comment: I tend to think that PrettyFaces navigation is simler, but I never recommend that blindly because it depends on your goals. If you want to use PrettyFaces as a URL-rewriting library only, then using it's navigation features (aka, `return "pretty:mappingId";` would make it harder to replace PrettyFaces if you ever wanted to use another library. Not sure why you would, but it's something to consider. Also, did what I post answer your original question correctly?

Comment: I have a similar issue. In my case I dont need any id
e.g. in above example
I have the following case


in faces-config

<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>from-outcome</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/topics/view.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </redirect>
</navigation-case>

...
...

while in pretty-cofig


<url-mapping>
    <pattern value="/topics" />
    <view-id value="/topics/view.xhtml" />
</url-mapping>

...
...

but when I use this
It redirects me to .../topics.xhtml
instead of .../topics
..
@Lincoln any idea of the why it added extension. And how to resolve this